# How to make rowspan add 1 and new row added last with javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I want to add new row under name and age. The colspan of ApplyPeople will be added to 1.But I failed, here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add').click(function () {
        newrow = '<tr><td style="width:25%">John</td><td style="width:55%">20</td></tr>';
        $('#apply').rowspan = $('#apply').rowspan + 1;
        $('#staTable tr:xie').append(newrow);       
    });
 }
```

Before click, html code:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:20%" rowspan=1 id="apply">
        applyPeople<br />
        <input type="button" id="add" value="add">
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%">name</td>
    <td style="width:55%">age</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:20%">zone</td>
    <td style="width:80%" colspan=2>letter</td>
</tr>
```

After click, html code:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:20%" rowspan=2 id="apply">
        apply<br />
        <input type="button" id="add" value="add">
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%">name</td>
    <td style="width:55%">age</td>
</tr>
<tr id="xie" >
    <td style="width:25%">John</td>
    <td style="width:55%">20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td style="width:20%">zone</td>
   <td style="width:80%" colspan=2>letter</td>
</tr>
```

What is wrong with my code? Who can help me?

Comment: Sorry you're right, didn't notice. I need more coffee ...

Comment: try something like `$('#appPeople').attr("rowspan", parseInt($('#appPeople').attr("rowspan")) + 1);` and `$(newrow).insertAfter($('#staTable tr:first'));`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen tr: is not the first,it is sixth.But when tr:sixed is used,it did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to achieve what you want:

Comments in code for js, - and also in your html, start your rowspan off as 2 (or the number of rows you start in your table) and get rid of the colspan in the second row - the rowspan handles the missing column

```js
$('#addPeople').click(function () {
        newrow = '<tr><td style="width:25%">John</td><td style="width:55%">20</td></tr>';
        var rowspan = parseInt($('#appPeople').attr('rowspan')) + 1; // use attr to get the rowspan and parseInt to make it an int
        
        $('#appPeople').attr('rowspan', rowspan);  // use attr to set the rowspan
        
        $('#staTable tr:eq(0)').after(newrow);       // use after if you want to add it after the first row, eq(0) means get the first instance of
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="staTable">
<tr>
<td style="width:20%" rowspan=2 id="appPeople">
applyPeople<br />
<input type="button" id="addPeople" value="">
</td>
<td style="width:25%">name</td>
<td style="width:55%">age</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td style="width:20%">zone</td>
   <td style="width:80%">letter</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Think the op wants the new row to be added after the first TR, according to hes example.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen have edited so that the inserted row appears after the first row (like in example)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen@Pete,'#staTable tr:eq(0) is not the first tr.I hava tried "var index=6;   '#staTable tr:eq(index); index++",But it did nothing.

Comment: @Snow if you want the 6 tr, then index would have to be 5. since you start on 0.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen，yes,eq(5) works fine.Actually,I want to use eq(index), index is a global variable.I had tried var index=5; eq(index),but it failed.

Comment: Make sure it looks like `$('#staTable tr:eq('+ index +')')`

Comment: @snow No problem